# проценты в dB python

Tags: python, google-maps-api

Я пытаюсь определить своё местоположение с помощью googlemaps api.
 Для этого мне нужно предоставить им  эти 2 параметра(остальные нужные им параметры, я уже предоставил, остались эти):

- **signalToNoiseRatio** (The current signal to noise ratio measured in dB).
- **signalS trength** (The current signal strength measured in dBm.)

Данные которые у меня есть:

```py
{'Signal' : '44%', 'Radio type' : '802.11n', 'Basic rates (Mbps)' : '1 2 5.5 11', ' Other rates (Mbps)' : '6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54'}
```

Что думаю я:

Мне кажется что мне просто нужно сконвертировать signal в dBm и dB, но как это сделать я не знаю.

**Как мне получить нужные мне 2 параметра?**